# why terminal mail doesn't work?

Tags: bash, email, terminal

I've just installed mail

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

And I tried to send mail though a pipeline:

```
echo "message" | mail -s "subject" my@email.com
```

But I don't receive any mails on my inbox.

Why doesn't work? Do I need another package?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a MTA (mail transport agent - e.g., sendmail, qmail) installed?

Comment: For comparison, try sending it to just your user name without a domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved!
I had to edit this file and set this variables /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf’:

```
root=username@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=
hostname=username@gmail.com
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=username
AuthPass=password
FromLineOverride=YES
```